# manipulation with dynamically added textfield values

Tags: java, swing

`jPanel` consists 5 `jTextFields`. I am adding dynamically `jPanels` by `addButton`. And retrieving dynamically added `jPanel` values by `saveButton`.  The code of `saveButton`:

```
private void writefile(JPanel panel_name, PrintWriter file){
        Component[] children = panel_name.getComponents();                   
        for (Component sp : children) {
            if (sp instanceof subPanel) {
                Component[] spChildren = ((subPanel)sp).getComponents();
                  int count=1;
                for (Component spChild : spChildren) {
                    if (spChild instanceof JTextField) {

                    String text = "";
                    if(count==1)
                    text=((JTextField)spChild).getText();

                    if(count==2)
                    text=((JTextField)spChild).getText();

                    if(count==4)
                    text=((JTextField)spChild).getText();

                    if(count==5)
                    text=((JTextField)spChild).getText();

                    if(count==3)
                    text=((JTextField)spChild).getText();

                    if(text.equals(null) || text.equals("")) {

                    }
                       else{
                    file.write(text);       
                        }                                               
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I have entered `1, 2, 4, 5, 3` to jTextFields and when I click saveButton, output I got jTextField values as: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.
Even if I write `count==4` after `count==2`, anyway output I am getting in ordered line. I would like to ask how can I get the value of `count==4` after `count==2`?

Comment: Would you be able to complete the code example? `count` isn't being incremented anywhere I can see, for example.

Comment: This is not your exact code. How is the value of `count` changing? It always the same! The `for (Component spChild : spChildren)` gets all the JTextFields in order, and hence you get that output. Give your exact code, and then we can help.

Comment: Moreover, your code in all the checks, i.e. `count==1`, `count==2` etc is the same. Then how do you expect different outputs!

Comment: I have solved my problem. I totally changed the code, with getter method everything become more easy.